# ASP.NET MVC Razor is printing local inline if statement result when it should only set local Razor variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, if-statement, razor

I have some Razor code which uses a custom attribute to basically see if I should display a link.  I'm using two local Razor variables (`Edit` and `Delete`) so I don't have to call this function multiple times on the page.

```
@{bool Edit = false;}
@{bool Delete = false;}

@(User.IsAuthorized("EmployeePhotos/Employees/Edit") ? Edit = true : Edit = false)
@(User.IsAuthorized("EmployeePhotos/Employees/Delete") ? Delete = true : Delete = false)
```

While the inline if statement is setting the local Razor variables correctly... it's printing `True True` on the page itself.

It doesn't do this with a normal `if` statement:

```
@if (User.IsAuthorized("EmployeePhotos/Employees/Edit"))
{
    Edit = true;
}
```

Why is the one-liner `if` statement printing my function result but the normal `if` statement isn't?

Comment: Any content within the `@()` parenthesis is [evaluated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor) and rendered to the output. In your case it is evaluated to `True` and will be rendered to the output. If you just want to assign use `@{}` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
@{
    bool Edit = User.IsAuthorized("EmployeePhotos/Employees/Edit");
    bool Delete = User.IsAuthorized("EmployeePhotos/Employees/Delete");
}

<p>Has access to edit functionality: @Edit</p>
<p>Has access to delete functionality: @Delete</p>

@if (Edit)
{
    <h2>Only for edit</h2>
}
```